# Multiple Quartz schedule for each time zone

Tags: quartz-scheduler

I have a quartz job that runs at 3 pm every day (server time). What I'd like to do is have it run at 3 pm but for each time zone in the US. The quartz job triggers an email to my users and I'd like everyone to get it at 3 pm their time. Is the best way to do this just to setup multiple schedules and then query the database for the users in that trigger's set timezone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your idea is pretty much the best and cleanest approach I can think of. One job with several triggers - identical except different time zone. Inside the job you can easily retrieve which time zone are you currently working with:

```
void execute(JobExecutionContext context) {
    TimeZone tz = ((CronTrigger)context.getTrigger()).getTimeZone();
    //find all users in tz
}
```